# Is it possible to do a depth first search iteratively without copying visited nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, tree-search

### Background

- I am searching a 2D grid for a word.
- We can search left/right and up/down.
- For example, in this grid, searching for `"abef"` starting at `(0,0)` will return `True`

**Example (grid1):**

[image: Grid 1]

### Where I'm at

- The recursive version gives expected results (see `dfs_rec()` below).
- The iterative version also gives expected results (see `dfs_iter()` below). However, in this version I am making a copy of the `visited` set onto the stack at every node.

### My question is

- Is there a way to avoid the copy (`visited.copy()`) in the iterative version, and add/remove to a single `visited` set as in the recursive version?

### Further details and stuff I've tried...

- In `dfs_rec()` there is a single `set()` named `visited`, and it's changed via `visited.add((row,col))` and `visited.remove((row,col))`
- But in `dfs_iter()` I am pushing `visited.copy()` onto the stack each time, to prevent nodes from being marked as visited incorrectly.
- I have seen some iterative examples where they use a single `visited` set, without making copies or removing anything from the set, but that does not give me the right output in these examples (see `dfs_iter_nocopy()` using `grid3` below).

**As an example, take this grid:**

[image: Grid 2]

- Say you search for `"abexxxxxx"` (covering the entire grid), the expected output will be `True`

[image: Grid 2a]

- But `dfs_iter_nocopy()` will give incorrect output on one of `grid2` or `grid3` (they are just mirrored, one will pass and one will fail), depending on the order you push nodes onto the stack.
- What's happening is, when you search for `"abexxxxxx"`, it searches a path like this (only hitting 5 x's, while it needs 6).

[image: Grid 2b]

- It marks the `x` at `(1,0)` as visited, and when it's time to search that branch, it stops at `(1,0)`, like this:

[image: Grid 2c]

### Code

```
def width  (g): return len(g)
def height (g): return len(g[0])
def valid (g,r,c): return r>=0 and c>=0 and r<height(g) and c<width(g)

def dfs_rec (grid, word, row, col, visited):

    if not valid(grid, row, col): return False  # (row,col) off board
    if (row,col) in visited:      return False  # already checked
    if grid[row][col] != word[0]: return False  # not right path

    if grid[row][col] == word: # len(word)==1
        return True

    visited.add((row,col))

    if dfs_rec(grid, word[1:], row, col+1, visited): return True
    if dfs_rec(grid, word[1:], row+1, col, visited): return True
    if dfs_rec(grid, word[1:], row, col-1, visited): return True
    if dfs_rec(grid, word[1:], row-1, col, visited): return True

    # Not found on this path, don't block for other paths
    visited.remove((row,col))

    return False

def dfs_iter (grid, start_word, start_row, start_col, start_visited):

    stack = [ (start_row, start_col, start_word, start_visited) ]

    while len(stack) > 0:

        row,col,word,visited = stack.pop()

        if not valid(grid, row, col): continue
        if (row,col) in visited: continue
        if grid[row][col] != word[0]: continue

        if grid[row][col] == word:
            return True

        visited.add((row,col))

        stack.append( (row, col+1, word[1:], visited.copy()) )
        stack.append( (row+1, col, word[1:], visited.copy()) )
        stack.append( (row, col-1, word[1:], visited.copy()) )
        stack.append( (row-1, col, word[1:], visited.copy()) )

    return False

def dfs_iter_nocopy (grid, start_word, start_row, start_col):

    visited = set()
    stack = [ (start_row, start_col, start_word) ]

    while len(stack) > 0:

        row,col,word = stack.pop()

        if not valid(grid, row, col): continue
        if (row,col) in visited: continue
        if grid[row][col] != word[0]: continue

        if grid[row][col] == word:
            return True

        visited.add((row,col))

        stack.append( (row, col+1, word[1:]) )
        stack.append( (row+1, col, word[1:]) )
        stack.append( (row, col-1, word[1:]) )
        stack.append( (row-1, col, word[1:]) )

    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':

    grid  = [ 'abc', 'def', 'hij' ]
    grid2 = [ 'abx', 'xex', 'xxx' ]
    grid3 = [ 'xba', 'xex', 'xxx' ]

    print( dfs_rec(grid, 'abef', 0, 0, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_rec(grid, 'abcd', 0, 0, set() ) == False )
    print( dfs_rec(grid, 'abcfjihde', 0, 0, set() ) == True )
    print( dfs_rec(grid, 'abefjihd', 0, 0, set() ) == True )
    print( dfs_rec(grid, 'abefjihda', 0, 0, set() ) == False )
    print( dfs_rec(grid, 'abefjihi', 0, 0, set() ) == False )

    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abc', 0, 0, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abef', 0, 0, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abcd', 0, 0, set() ) == False )
    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abcfjihde', 0, 0, set() ) == True )
    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abefjihd', 0, 0, set() ) == True )
    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abefjihda', 0, 0, set() ) == False )
    print( dfs_iter(grid, 'abefjihi', 0, 0, set() ) == False )

    print( dfs_rec(grid2, 'abexxxxxx', 0, 0, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_iter(grid2, 'abexxxxxx', 0, 0, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_iter_nocopy(grid2, 'abexxxxxx', 0, 0 ) == True   )
    print( dfs_rec(grid3, 'abexxxxxx', 0, 2, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_iter(grid3, 'abexxxxxx', 0, 2, set() ) == True   )
    print( dfs_iter_nocopy(grid3, 'abexxxxxx', 0, 2 ) == True   ) # <-- Problem, prints False
```

Comment: You need to push an indicator that you called `visited.add` onto your `stack`. When you pop that indicator, you need to call `visited.remove`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noticed that the recursive version was able to use a single `visited` accumulator by resetting it with `visited.remove((row,col))` when backtracking. So the same can be done here by imitating the function call stack so that we know when backtracking occurs.

```
def dfs_iter_nocopy (grid, start_word, start_row, start_col):
    visited = []   # order now matters
    last_depth = 0 # decreases when backtracking 
    stack = [ (start_row, start_col, start_word, last_depth+1) ]

    while len(stack) > 0:
        row, col, word, depth = stack.pop()
        if not valid(grid, row, col): continue
        while last_depth >= depth: # just backtracked
            last_depth -= 1
            visited.pop()          # simulate returning from the call stack
        if (row,col) in visited: continue
        if grid[row][col] != word[0]: continue
        
        if grid[row][col] == word:
            return True

        visited.append((row,col))
        last_depth = depth
        depth += 1 # simulate adding recursive call to the call stack
        stack.append( (row, col+1, word[1:], depth) )
        stack.append( (row+1, col, word[1:], depth) )
        stack.append( (row, col-1, word[1:], depth) )
        stack.append( (row-1, col, word[1:], depth) )
    return False
```

The depth will increase as a new tile is explored, but decrease as we exhaust the possibilities for a particular path and revert to an earlier fork. This is what I mean by backtracking.

edit: variable name

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be if Do not extend a path to a state if the resulting path would have a loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).